# При клике на ссылку закрытие меню (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня есть меню для мобильной версии; я не силен в `js` и `jquery`.
Я не понимаю, как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на ссылку меню закрывалось.

https://prnt.sc/pud0ld

Сам сайт https://web-help.github.io/

Comment: а что уже сделано? код меню есть хоть какой-то?

Comment: код меню  есть но только автоматический скролл сам код  https://codepen.io/web-help/pen/yLLEorY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть скрипт - https://web-help.github.io/js/script.min.js на 30 строке есть функция

```
$('.header__burger').click(function() {
  $('.header__burger').toggleClass('header__burger--active'),
    $('.header__burger').hasClass('header__burger--active')
      ? ($('.header__menu').css('display', 'flex'), $('body,html').toggleClass('hidden'))
      : ($('.header__menu').css('display', 'none'), $('body,html').toggleClass('hidden'));
});
```

Эта функция обрабатывает кнопку бургер по нажатию. Тоесть закрывает меню, то что вам нужно по нажатию по ссылке в меню. Вы можете добавить селектор, что бы эта функция выполнялась так же и по нажатию нассылку таким образом:

```
$('.header__burger, .scrollto').click(function() {
  $('.header__burger').toggleClass('header__burger--active'),
    $('.header__burger').hasClass('header__burger--active')
      ? ($('.header__menu').css('display', 'flex'), $('body,html').toggleClass('hidden'))
      : ($('.header__menu').css('display', 'none'), $('body,html').toggleClass('hidden'));
});
```